# Physical Meaning of Inexact differential

Tags: calculus

Inexact differential is widely used in thermodynamics for path dependent quantities and to determine the rate equation of the first law of thermodynamics

The mathematical expression for first law of thermodynamics is:

$\delta{Q} = dU + \delta{W}$

here U is the total internal energy of the system, Q is the heat supplied and W is the work done by the system.

Since U doesnot depends on the path, we used  $dU$

So,dividing the initial equation by $\delta{t}$, we get

$\frac{\delta{Q}}{\delta{t}} = \frac{dU}{\delta{t}} +\frac{\delta{W}}{\delta{t}}$

Taking limit for each of these quantities at $\delta{t}$ approaches Zero, we have

$\lim_{\delta{t}\to 0 }\frac{\delta{Q}}{\delta{t}} = \lim_{\delta{t}\to 0 } \frac{dU}{\delta{t}} + \lim_{\delta{t}\to 0 } \frac{\delta{W}}{\delta{t}}$

$\implies \frac{dQ}{dt} = \frac{dU}{dt} + \frac{dW}{dt}$

Can anyone help me sort out, after we take limits on both sides, how did $\delta$ get converted to $d$?

Comment: That seems wrong, unless $t$ is just the variable parametrizing the path (in which case it really could have been $dt$ the whole time).

Comment: Here $t$ is the notation for time

Comment: Yeah, in that case you're moving along one particular path anyway, so everything can be $d$'s once you have focused on a particular path.

Comment: @Ian ok,It should be $dt$ then right? and talking about the limits, $\delta$ get converted to $d$ beacuse at $dt$ approaching to zero ,we are dealing with a particular point in a path?

Comment: Really finite changes should be denoted as $\Delta t$ regardless of whether anything is exact or inexact, but in any case the differentials along a single path will be written with $d$ not $\delta$.